# Android Activity Resize

Tags: android, android-activity

What method need I @Overload in order to change the size of the Activity when it is first loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not depend on the "size of the Activity". You have to resize your root container. Which is generally a Layout. You can try a scale animation on your layout to see the effect of resizing.